# Bluetooth Communication in thread or Service in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, bluetooth

I am developing app which has bluetooth communication involved. The bluetooth communication should go on even if the Activity that sets up the connection closes down. First, I have thought of using Service for this and that seemed to be right way. But, in Bluetooth chat example the communication happens in another thread and not in Service. I have used that code in my app and its working properly. Is using Thread for bluetooth communication proper or do I need to make use of Service only? The bluetooth communication should be active till my app is in RAM and it should not matter if I switch between activities.

Comment: Can someone let me know if its proper to have bluetooth communication in thread rather than in Service? I have tried with thread and its working for now but want to be sure so that I do not need to change the code later on.

Answer (score 0):

Well a seperated Thread is  not  differnd then a service in you case, except that it follows the activity life cycle of Android, but a Thread might be killed and no state can be recovered. Android will try to restarted a service once it was killed.

Answer (score 0):

A little too late to answer your query, but better late than never I suppose.
I have worked on an application that has the bluetooth communication between two devices and I would like to summarize my experience.
A service we use normally when we want do some background process that is not very heavy, in a way, I mean the service (if it is huge) will block my main UI thread hence slowing down your OS or ANR may be, which is what we don't want.

The bluetooth communcation is an ever running process which should be done using a Thread only as this will work as a separate thread and wont have any impact on the main UI thread.
Please correct me if I am wrong.